# Copy value from matching index in another dataframe after criteria matched

Tags: python, pandas

With the test Pandas dataframe below I am trying to copy a value from matching index in another dataframe after certain criteria is matched.

This is a snip from the dataframe called `data2`:

```
                 Signal Value2
2013-01-01 09:00:00 1.0 NaN
2013-01-01 10:00:00 1.0 NaN
2013-01-01 11:00:00 1.0 NaN
2013-01-01 12:00:00 1.0 NaN
2013-01-01 13:00:00 1.0 NaN
2013-01-01 14:00:00 -1.0 NaN
```

and this is a snip from `data`:

```
    value
2013-01-01 09:00:00 9
2013-01-01 10:00:00 10
2013-01-01 11:00:00 11
2013-01-01 12:00:00 12
2013-01-01 13:00:00 13
2013-01-01 14:00:00 14
2013-01-01 15:00:00 15
2013-01-01 16:00:00 16
2013-01-02 09:00:00 33
2013-01-02 10:00:00 34
```

So when `data2` `Signal` at `2013-01-01 14:00:00` shows `-1` I want to copy the corresponding `value` from `data` which is `14` and copy this to `data2` `Values2`.

Here is the code to test this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
index = pd.date_range('2013-1-1',periods=100,freq='1h')
data = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(100)), columns=['value'], index=index)

signal = 1.0
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data=signal, columns=['Signal'], index=index)
data2['Signal']['2013-01-01 14:00:00'] = -1.0
data2['Value2'] = np.nan
start = datetime.time(9,0,0)
end = datetime.time(16,00,0)
data = data.between_time(start,end)
```

This will ultimately be used on a large dataframe and will involve multiple days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be something like this?

```
data2.loc[data2.Signal == -1, 'Value2'] = data.loc[data2.Signal == -1, 'value']
```